# Knockout clearing field in view model after submission

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

How can I clear the value of department name in my view model after I submit the department to the server to be saved?  Here is my code:

```
self.AddDepartmentModel.AddDepartment = function () {
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(this, { deep: true, observable: false });
    if (self.AddDepartmentModel.errors().length == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Department/Add/",
            type: 'post',
            data: ko.toJSON(self.AddDepartmentModel),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#success').html('Department Added Successfully.');
                $("#success").dialog({
                    dialogClass: 'noclose',
                    autoOpen: true,
                    show: "blind",
                    hide: "explode",
                    modal: true,
                    open: function(event, ui) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $('#success').dialog('close');
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                });
                self.ListOfDepartments.GetListOfAllDepartments();
                $("#departmentNameTextbox").val("");
                self.AddDepartmentModel.DepartmentName = null;
            }
        });
    } else {
        self.AddDepartmentModel.errors.showAllMessages();
        return;
    }
};
```

I want the field to be cleared after the submit button is pressed.  If I just make the field value an empty string and hit submit again it submits the value that was in the text box after I cleared it.  Any suggestions how to clear the value of DepartmentName?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

i assume that self.AddDepartmentModel.DepartmentName is a observable property, since it is bound to a textbox and you get the user entered value. if that's the case, try

```
self.AddDepartmentModel.DepartmentName(null);
```

instead of

```
$("#departmentNameTextbox").val("");
self.AddDepartmentModel.DepartmentName = null;
```

Comment: I have had weird experiences using null but have found desired functionality using the empty string, ''.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive old question, but I also wanted to mention that you could do the following:

`self.AddDepartmentModel.DepartmentName(undefined);`